# Modifications by phrasal verbs

Tags: verbs

What modifications do phrasal verbs make

There are two sentences

> I ***shaved*** my beard.
>
> I ***shaved off*** my beard/I ***shaved*** my beard ***off***.

What is the difference between these two sentences?

Answer (score 1):

According to dictionaries, "shave off" means to remove *a small amount* of something from the total amount.

[Thefreedictionary.com](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/shave+off)

Shave off = To eliminate some small amount of a total: *This aerodynamic racing suit will shave off a full second from your time.*

But, according to the same dictionary, when it comes to a mustache/beard, "shave off" means to *completely remove* it:  *I've decided to shave off my mustache.*

Check for more examples in [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/shave-off) and [Oxford Learner's](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/shave-off) dictionary.